# Negation of two things

Tags: negation

Which one of the following is correct?

> We don't need to know A, nor B, individually. Instead, we only need the sum of A and B.

or

> We don't need to know A and B individually. Instead, we only need the sum of A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"We need to know neither A nor B... " or "We don't need to know either A or B..." is correct here.

Comment: I think "nor do we need to know B" is implied. You could probably leave out "instead" in the second sentence as well. Grammatically I think both are acceptable.

Comment: @Misneac Your comment belongs to the question, not this answer. :)